# angular 2 pathMatch routing doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I try to pass [angular2 heroes-tour](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html)

I have issue with routing part.

project structure:

[image]

In tutorial written that if write in template:

**app.component.html:**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<nav>
    <a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
    <a routerLink="/heroes">Heroes</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and configure routing like this:

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule }   from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent }        from './app.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroesComponent }     from './heroes.component';
import { HeroService }         from './hero.service';
import {DashBoardComponent} from "./dashboard.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {
                path: 'heroes',
                component: HeroesComponent
            }, {
                path: 'dashboard',
                component: DashBoardComponent,
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }, {
                path: 'detail/:id',
                component: HeroDetailComponent
            },
        ])
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeroDetailComponent,
        HeroesComponent,
        DashBoardComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        HeroService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

then

> To see these changes in your browser, go to the application root (/)
>   and reload. The app displays the dashboard and we can navigate between
>   the dashboard and the heroes.

In my case I see:

[image]

Thus redirect to /dashboard doesn't happen after reloading page.

What do I wrong?

**P.S.**
Feel free to ask me add more details to post.

Comment: Did you check the console for any errors?  Perhaps it couldn't find one of your components?

Comment: did you add the RouterModule in app.module.ts?.

Comment: @Jaime Torres console is empty. if click to link - each components opens properly

Comment: @Rumes Shyaman, Yes, I have added

Comment: can you add the whole routing code?.

Comment: @Rumes Shyaman I have added full app.component.ts

Comment: that is app.module.ts ?.

Comment: @Rumes Shyaman You are right. sorry for mistake.

Comment: yep you should leave path ' ' to redirect on start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the browser launches at `http://localhost:3000` url when you do `npm start` which do not match any URL into your route config so you need to add below redirect rule inside `RouterModule.forRoot` so the app shows the `dashboard` when it starts and you can see a nice URL in the browser address bar that says `/dashboard` :

```
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/dashboard',
  pathMatch: 'full'
}
```